# Entity framework filtering data by time

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

I am so sorry from the question, but I can not take a period from a `DateTime`. for exemple: If I have date `"10.10.2016 7:00", 10.10.2016 10:00"`, I need to take only the rows with the time between "6:00" and "8:00". Next is my code by return an error : `"can not use TimeOfDay ",`help me please

```
ds.TrafficJamMorning = (from row in orderQuery
                        where row.AcceptedTime.TimeOfDay >= new TimeSpan(6, 30, 0) &&
                        row.AcceptedTime.TimeOfDay <= new TimeSpan(9, 30, 0)
                        group row by row.AcceptedTime.Date
                        into grp
                        select new TrafficJamPeriodInfo
                        {
                             CurrentDateTime = grp.Key,
                             ReceptionCount = grp.Count(r => r.OrderOriginId == (int)OrderOrigin.Reception),
                             InternetCount = grp.Count(r => r.OrderOriginId == (int)OrderOrigin.Internet),
                             ExchangeSystemCount = grp.Count(r => r.OrderOriginId == (int)OrderOrigin.ExchangeSystem)
                        }).ToList();
```

Comment: First of all time span doesn't represent a point in time, but rather a "quantity" of time. What type is `TimeOfDay`? Is it a `DateTime`? then you can do something like this (method chain here): `where(x=>x.TimeOfDay.Hour>7 and x.TimeOfDay.Hour<10)`

Comment: @j0ey_wh I guess `AcceptedTime` is a `DateTime` meanwhile `TimeOfDay` is a `TimeSpan`

Comment: @Sid no wonder it doesn't build

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TimeOfDay` Is not supported by the linq provider and it does not know how to parse it into sql. Use instead [`DbFunctions.CreateTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions.createtime(v=vs.113).aspx):

*Also instantiate the timespans before the linq query so you do not instantiate a new object every time*

```
var startTime = new TimeSpan(6, 30, 0);
var endTime = new TimeSpan(9, 30, 0);

var result = (from row in orderQuery
              let time = DbFunctions.CreateTime(row.AcceptedTime.Hour, row.AcceptedTime.Minute, row.AcceptedTime.Second)
              where time  >= startTime &&
                    time  <= endTime
              group row by DbFunctions.TruncateTime(row.AcceptedTime) into grp
              select new TrafficJamPeriodInfo
              {
                   CurrentDateTime = grp.Key,
                   ReceptionCount = grp.Count(r => r.OrderOriginId == (int)OrderOrigin.Reception),
                   InternetCount = grp.Count(r => r.OrderOriginId == (int)OrderOrigin.Internet),
                   ExchangeSystemCount = grp.Count(r => r.OrderOriginId == (int)OrderOrigin.ExchangeSystem)
              }).ToList();
```

Looking again at the question - If all you want to check is that it is between 2 hours then use the `Hour` property *(This won't be nice to write if you want to check for example `Hour` and `Minues` and in that case I'd go for my first suggestion)*:

```
var result = (from row in orderQuery
              where row.AcceptedTime.Hour >= 6
                    row.AcceptedTime.Hour < 8
              group row by DbFunctions.TruncateTime(row.AcceptedTime) into grp
              select new TrafficJamPeriodInfo
              {
                   CurrentDateTime = grp.Key,
                   ReceptionCount = grp.Count(r => r.OrderOriginId == (int)OrderOrigin.Reception),
                   InternetCount = grp.Count(r => r.OrderOriginId == (int)OrderOrigin.Internet),
                   ExchangeSystemCount = grp.Count(r => r.OrderOriginId == (int)OrderOrigin.ExchangeSystem)
              }).ToList();
```

Comment: :) I need also the min

Comment: I must to change row.AcceptedTime.TimeOfDay with time , on first exemple, it's right?

Comment: @SilviaParfeni - So I think go for the first suggestion because when it is both hours and minutes it is fine that the minutes is smaller if the hour is bigger, and if the hour is the same then the minutes must be bigger. Possible but a less readable more complex where clause

Comment: @SilviaParfeni - och of course, stupid me haha. corrected answer

Comment: AFAIK .Date is not supported on LinqToEF.

Comment: Great, and I think you would also want to write that like ".. row.AcceptedTime.Hour * 60 + row.AcceptedTime.Minute >= 6 * 60 + 30 .."

Comment: @CetinBasoz - In any case I think it is best to go with option 1. Option 2 is there for the case that he wants to check only one of the properties.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following where clause on my IQueryable:

```
var query = dbContext.GetAllItems().AsQueryable();

//... other filters

if(MusBeBetween6and8){
    query = query.Where(item => item.AcceptedTime.Hour > 6 && item.AcceptedTime.Hour < 8);
}

//... other filters

return query.ToList();
```

Hope it helps. This also works for Oracle + Odac.

Comment: what is returned by GetAllItems? Is it a list?

Comment: @zolty13 I think back then I built my repository-layer as extension methods on my dbcontext. GetAllItems was just a representation for one of the methods from my repository. It would have been an IQueryable<Item> I guess, so the AsQueryable was redundant, but shows you that adding extra filters would show in the query as it is still Linq-2-Entities.

Answer (score 0):

```
ds.TrafficJamMorning = (from row in orderQuery
                        where 
                            DbFunctions.DiffMinutes( DbFunctions.TruncateTime(row.AcceptedTime), row.AcceptedTime) >= 6 * 60 + 30 &&
                            DbFunctions.DiffMinutes( DbFunctions.TruncateTime(row.AcceptedTime), row.AcceptedTime) <= 9 * 60 + 30
                        group row by DbFunctions.TruncateTime(row.AcceptedTime)
                        into grp
                        select new TrafficJamPeriodInfo
                        {
                            CurrentDateTime = grp.Key,
                            ReceptionCount = grp.Count(r => r.OrderOriginId == (int)OrderOrigin.Reception),
                            InternetCount = grp.Count(r => r.OrderOriginId == (int)OrderOrigin.Internet),
                            ExchangeSystemCount = grp.Count(r => r.OrderOriginId == (int)OrderOrigin.ExchangeSystem)
                        }).ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem.

You can compare the date parts instead.

where row.Year > s.Year && r.Month > s.Month && row.Day > s.Day

Comment: so is not possible, a have more different date

Comment: You are not comparing Time in this way

Comment: where row.AcceptedTime.TimeOfDay >= new TimeSpan(6, 30, 0) &&
                        row.AcceptedTime.TimeOfDay <= new TimeSpan(9, 30, 0)